# Which UI library recommended to use with Angular2?

Tags: angular, primeng, ng-bootstrap

I am recently investigating whether we should utilize AngularJS 1 or Angular2 for a long-term product.

My biggest focus is on the availability of mature UI libraries to create appealing user interfaces, like AngularUI for Angular JS 1.

During researching I came across libraries such as PrimeNG [1] or ng-bootstrap [2], however I still wonder how mature they are, i.e. they should be free from major bugs and quite stable.

What is your experience with them and what further libraries can you recommend?

[1] http://www.primefaces.org/primeng 
[2] https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 is not even final so don't expect to have final libraries!

My experience with ngbootstrap is that it's almost feature complete (modals landed yesterady and datepicker is not yet available) but the features are very limited.

At some point I looked at primeng and it looked promising. However there are very few contributors (very active though) to the project.

There is also [angular material](https://github.com/angular/material2) backed by Google. So when Angular 2 will be final, you can expect this project to move forward very quickly.

In conclusion, if you need something very stable for next month then go with Angular 1 or React. If you need something quickly but can wait 3-4 months for something stable then go for Angular 2 (or React? ;)